# Aligning 3 <li> elements relative to the width of the page in CSS3

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a responsive web with the next layout:

[image]

The image is self descriptive but what I'm trying to accomplish is the next:

```
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="first.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="second.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="third.jpg"></li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><img src="first.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="second.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="third.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

All the images inside the `<li>` will be squares of 350px. My idea is that they fit inside the 3 images `<ul>` with the correct size (depending on the width, they will be resized). Also they must be the first and last with no margin and the one in the middel centered with a little margin in each side.

I know how to accomplish this in a "old" fashioned way, creating various `<div>` with float left, float right, etc. but I was wondering if exists an easy way to do it in CSS3 because I only need to support modern browsers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using display: table, table-row,table-cell, to get the desired effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CSS3 box sizing is useful:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201104/controlling_width_with_css3_box-sizing/

I'm not sure if that does exactly the same as the old fashioned way, though. Maybe you should just stick to the original CSS because that ensures you can also easily make changes to the margin and padding afterwards.

Good luck!